# How to open executable binary without running it in ollydbg?

Tags: portable-executable, ollydbg

When I try to open a PE executable , it's automatically run.

How can I just open it statically without running it? I just want to see the binary file in hex format.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want see it in "hex format" - just use any of hex viewer or hex editor. There are lots of them, including plugins for file managers (FAR, Total Commander) or hex editors like WinHex.

If you want to see it disassembled - use disassembler. IDA, hiew, etc.

---

Or, start OllyDbg, than in menu select View -> File .

Also, there is PE file header view mode (right mouse button (RMB) -> Special -> PE header). You can edit (RMB -> Binary -> Edit) and save file (RMB -> save) too.

You can read this in OllyDbg help, "Tips and tricks", 1st line.

Comment: thanks! In the `RMB -> Binary -> Edit` dialog,there's a "Keep Size" option which is checked by default,what does that mean?

Comment: If the answer of Abyx helped you should vote it up, don't you think? So +1

Answer (score 0):

for viewing your code in hex mode do this:

`view` > `file`

or

`view` > `Executable modules` > select module > right click > `View executable file`

your second question in comment : there's a "Keep Size" option which is checked by default,what does that mean?

keep size is not important. edit binary let you to change bytes. if you tick keep size it let you only change bytes you selected. if you don't tick you can change all bytes start from you select.